# What is the best code for checking if the names under columns with the same names, but in two different dataframes match? In python, using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have two dataframes life_exp_mean_top_10 and health_exp_mean_top_10, both have the column 'country'.

I want to see if the names of the countries with the top 10 life expectancy(life_exp_mean_top_10) equals the names of the top 10 government health spending ( health_exp_mean_top_10) countries.

I'm using jupyter notebook with python 3 and pandas. 
DF1

```
life_exp_mean_top_10

country

Andorra        79.770833

Japan          79.596078

Switzerland    78.956863

Iceland        78.821569

Sweden         78.578431

Greece         78.066667

Spain          77.962745

Norway         77.898039

Canada         77.870588
```

DF2

```
health_exp_mean_top_10

country

Luxembourg       4353.125

Norway           4166.250

Monaco           3573.125

Denmark          3420.000

Iceland          3071.875

Switzerland      2915.625

Sweden           2686.875

Germany          2649.375

United States    2646.250

Austria          2635.000

Italy          77.827451
```

Comment: you just want to see if the values from your first df country are present in the 2nd ? try `df2[df2['Country'].isin(df1['County'])]` it's better if you post your target output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all 10 at once efficiently you should use sets

```
set(df1.iloc[0:9,'country']) == set(df2.iloc[0:9,'country'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter:

```
set(df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)['country'][:10]) == set(df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)['country'][:10])
```

If you want them to be both equal and in the same order:

```
all(df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)['country'][:10] == df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)['country'][:10])
```